# Junit Reduce Detailed Log of Console

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

is there a way to limit log of junit at spring-boot? Below is result of my `JSONAssert.assertEquals`, because of size of `body` is too large to show at console, i get `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I can not increase heap size of jvm by the way.

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /301c646a-bdc0-40e4-812e-16e3c83f37a3
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Accept=[application/json]}

Handler:
             Type = ...
           Method = ...

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"id":"301c646a-bdc0-40e4-812e-16e3c83f37a3","code":"70421341-199","...........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disabled all mock log

application.properties:

```
spring.test.mockmvc.print=none
```